# Delete a Dynamic Partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, diskpart

I want to delete my dynamic partition to install windows 7. I have 5 dynamic partitions currently on my hard disk. I don't want a single chunk of HD to be created. I just want one of the dynamic partitions to be made primary for installing windows 7. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to create **Primary Partition**, your Hard Disk has to be made **Basic**.

First [**IMPORTANT**], **backup** all data which is currently in your Hard Disk, because the conversion will result in data loss.

Get the **Windows Installation Media**, Start up with the Windows Installation Media.

Click **Install Now**.

Then **Repair your computer**.

Then a menu opens with a lot of options, there you have to open **Command Prompt**.

Then type the following commands carefully :

1.Run the Disk Partition Tool for Windows by the following command and press **ENTER**

```
diskpart
```

2.List all the disks which are currently onnected to the computer.

```
list disk
```

3.Note the disk number which has the *  **(star mark)** under the heading **Dyn**

4.Then run the command , if the disk number is 0 (in most cases)

```
select disk 0
```

5.Then , you have to list all the volumes

```
list vol
```

6.Delete all the listed volumes.

```
select vol 0
delete vol

select vol1
delete vol

select vol2
delete vol

select vol3
delete vol

select vol4
delete vol
```

7.Finally, convert into **Basic** disk by this command.

```
convert basic
```

Then you should be good to proceed and later create partitions during Windows Installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. However, I will answer the best I can with the information given.

It sounds like you want to simply convert one of your five existing dynamic partitions to a primary partition onto which you will install Windows, without creating a new partition.

This should be very easy. You should not have to convert it to a Primary, as the Windows installation will do this already. So put in your installation disk for Windows (assuming Windows 7, as the tag implies), and choose one of the partitions. You should be able to install Windows onto either Primary or dynamic partitions.

However, ideally you want to install Windows on the first physical partition on your hard drive. So I would receommend to burn a [gParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and boot into that. Now, using gParted, find the first partition on the drive and convert it to primary. Close gParted and remove disk.

Now, insert your Windows installation disk. Find the only Primary partition, and install windows there. Since there will be only one primary, and the primary is the first on the disk, then you can be sure that you are installing Windows on the first partition physically located on the disk.

Let me know if you have any trouble doing any of this.